# Will drilling a hole in a pane of glass reduce it's structural integrity?

Tags: structural-engineering, stresses, strength, glass, drain-waste-vent

I've got a glass box that measures 900mm x 450mm x 450mm.

The width of the glass is 6mm thick.

If I drill, cut, or grind a small hole in/through one of the faces; will it significantly affect the structural integrity of that piece of glass?

I'm concerned it might become prone to cracking, if for instance, I pick it up to move it.

I thought there might be some kind of ratio, or formula I can use to determine a safe size for a hole, a safe distance from the edge, and so on.

[image: glass box schematic diagram]

Comment: Yes, search for _Stress Concentration Factor_ for hole in plate. A rule of thumb is that the strength is at least 1/2 of the original strength under the same loading.

Comment: and just to add, it will also depend on where the hole is : centre, edge etc and also the internal loading - is it just air inside ie a display case or a fish tank full of water...

Comment: The estimates for stress concentration factor assume a smooth surface. If the hole is created by grinding or drilling, thus creating a huge number of surface defects, the strength of the sheet could be reduced to zero. The relevant field is [fracture mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_intensity_factor). Glass has a relatively low fracture toughness.

Comment: So you have a 100 gallon aquarium. The bottom and possibly the sides will be "tempered glass". Tempered glass requires special techniques normally left to professionals. There are a great number of aquariums with holes in the bottoms and sides that hold water and gravel ( combined weight ca 1000 lbs for your size). Are you going to put more weight than that ?

Comment: Just as an aside, your figure is extremely over-dimensioned.  It really only needs 4 numbers to completely define the geometry: 450, 450, 900, and "90 deg TYP". It would be much clearer that way.

Comment: @Mark and little angle marks for 90° instead of calling out all angles.

Comment: @Mark it's fine. I was trying to debug an issue with a new CAD-style application, it's all I had on hand, and I thought it was better than nothing. But I mean.. it's a box, it's not that complicated.

Comment: @blacksmith37 that's interesting, thanks. I think it's regular, untempered float glass. It's not quite an aquarium though; it's not going to be full of water. There will be gravel, etc. in the bottom, and maybe some water, but it will be relatively shallow. The idea is to fit it with a small airline tap, for draining it.

Comment: Can you use a standard size aquarium for your project?   You could order it with a hole , Standard holes are about one inch but maybe any size can be ordered or fittings are readily available  to match your tubing to one inch.

Comment: I don't know what a standard size aquarium is. I already have the glass box. The hole will probably be about a half inch.

Comment: But it can be smaller, if necessary.